# Collection of objects shared in different viewmodels

Tags: c#, wpf

in a Wpf application I've a collection of objects received via socket. Actually this collection is composed of a `Dictionary<Int, IMyObject>` And it's periodically filled/updated when an object is received on the socket.
I've 4 different `ViewModel`s that gets a subset of this collection (I've a MyObjectHolder which is a static instance holding this item and I get a subset of it doing something as

```
public IList<MyObject> ListTypeOne
{
    get
    {
        myList.Where(x => x.Type == myType)
    }
}
```

Each time an item is inserted/updated, I send a `NotifyOfPropertyChanged` on all the Properties from `TypeOne` to `TypeN`.

Is there a better implementation that I don't see?

I've not heavily stress tested it but I don't know how it performs when I've a large number of objects in the collection.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to CodeReview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the *best* solution, but here's what I would do.

1. Create a static instance of your collection (You've done this already.)
2. Have a service, or *something* that will periodically update your collection (You've done this already)
3. Push notifications to all ViewModels to force them to refresh their bindings. (The tricky part)

Now, there are a few ways you can handle number 3. One of these ways is to use **Caliburn Micro's Event Aggregator**. You can find out about it [here](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=The%20Event%20Aggregator).

Essentially, what it does is allow your ViewModels to *subscribe* to an event. Your service, or whatever it is that's updating your collection will *publish* the event, and all subscribers will be called. Pretty cool, right?

This allows you to keep your ViewModels nice and **decoupled**, which is what MVVM likes.

Now, I'm not saying you have to cave in and install Caliburn Micro (I wouldn't blame you if you didn't). There's no reason why you can't implement your own event aggregator, heck, there's probably loads of tutorials and sample code you can find if you use the right search terms.

Personally, I'm not a massive fan of using a framework, it just feels dirty, but that's down to my personal preference.

But anyway, give it a try and see what works for you.

Comment: Thanks that a vette solution of having a property changed handler

Comment: Btw Ive use caliburn in past,Now I'm moving To catel. .. another world